# Rails add fields to carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a `News` model with the Carrierwave AttachmentUploader mounted.

The json output looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 158,
  "title": "title1",
  "description": "desc1",
  "category": "ipsum",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "url": "/uploads/news/attachments/158/Tesla_P100D_App_v3.0_Review.mp4",
      "content_type": "application/mp4"
    }
  ],
  "created_at": "2017-02-14T08:34:14.119Z"
}
```

I want to add `thumbnail` field to Carrierwave to get the current output:

```
{
  "id": 158,
  "title": "title1",
  "description": "desc1",
  "category": "ipsum",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "url": "/uploads/news/attachments/158/Tesla_P100D_App_v3.0_Review.mp4",
      "content_type": "application/mp4",
         "thumbnail": {
              "name": "Tesla_P100D_App_v3.0_Review",
               "url": "/uploads/news/attachments/158/Tesla_P100D_App_v3.0_Review.png"
}
    }
     ],
  "created_at": "2017-02-14T08:34:14.119Z"
}
```

Here's my `NewsSerializer`:

```
class NewsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :description, :latitude, :longitude, :category, :tag_list, :avg_rating, :attachments,  :created_at

 def attachments
   a=[]
   object.attachments.each do |att|
         a << {url: att.url, content_type: att.content_type}
   end
   a
 end

end
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Don't add extra field you can achieve it with active record serializer. Can you update your complete json ?

Comment: @DipakG. just updated the code. I need to store `thumbnail` url which will be sent to me by client. How do I achieve it with the serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to do this by installing `ffmpeg` on my mac and `gem 'carrierwave-video-thumbnailer'`.

And added `thumb` to my NewsSerializer

```
 def attachments
   a=[]
   object.attachments.each do |att|
         a << {url: att.url, content_type: att.content_type, thumb: att.thumb}
   end
   a
 end
```